# Двигается или движется

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно говорить: "двигается" или "движется", "мурлыкает" или "мурлычет"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обе формы имеют право на существование (это так называемые избыточные глаголы) и различаются оттенками смысла.
Так, "движется" является более общим, чем "двигается".
Например: *"поезд движется по рельсам"*, а *"двери в его купе двигаются"*.